# Typescript filter array of object by another array of strings

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

i stuck at my typescript filter function.

I have an array of objects:

```
[
  {
    "id": 12345,
    "title": "Some title",
    "complexity": [
      {
        "slug": "1" // my search term
        "name": "easy"
      }, {
        "slug": "2" // my search term
        "name": "middle"
      },
{...}
```

And i have a array of strings with the allowed complexity:

```
public allowedComplexityArray:Array<string> = ["1"];
```

**My Task:** I only want to show objects with the allowed complexity of "1".

But somehow my function dont work and i dont know why:

```
allowedMeals = meals.filter(meal => {
    return meal.complexity.every(complexityObj => that.allowedComplexityArray.indexOf(complexityObj.slug) > -1)
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
let allowedMeals = data.filter(meal => {
    return meal.complexity.findIndex(complexityObj => 
        allowedComplexityArray.findIndex(m => m == complexityObj.slug) > -1) > -1
});
```

I'm using `findIndex` instead of `filter` in the `return` clause so it does not need to scan the whole array every time.